# C# version of CopyOnWriteArrayList

Tags: c#

We do not have C# version of [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) in standard library. Is there any other open source library available?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What behaviour are you looking for, exactly?

Comment: A thread able to iterate the collection, while another thread is able to add/remove element from the collection simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to [SynchronizedCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668265.aspx) in C#, this collection is similar to one CopyOnWriteArrayList in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which .NET version you are on you may use one of the [thread-safe collection classes in .Net 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx).

Comment: I saw them. But none of them provide such feature : A thread able to iterate the collection, while another is able to add/remove element from the collection simultaneously.